# Allow developer to install and login to existing Filemaker Pro 16 account

Tags: filemaker

I'm a developer who has been contracted to utilize the Filemaker API to automate some tasks on the client's website. They are using Filemaker Pro 16 and have it installed on their own machine. Is there a way for me to also install the software and use their login for development? It would be much easier than doing everything through the API.

Comment: As @AndreasT mentioned there is a number of APIs for FileMaker, official or third party. There are PHP API and Data API and also XML publishing. There is RestFM, API for nodeJS and Python. You need to specify what you use unless it is not related and you just want to login through FileMaker Pro. For access with FileMaker Pro you will need access to their network or port forwarding setup for the remote access

Comment: Is the client using FileMaker Server? If so, be aware the data API in FileMaker 16 is a public beta and will expire. If they will update to the next version, it might not be an issue, but the next version may change from the current beta. The XML api is used by all other apis that Nicolai mentions, and should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the FileMaker API for PHP.

Yes, just install FileMaker Pro or preferably FileMaker Pro Advanced and get a full access or at least layout creation/edit access login to the database from your client. You need a license for FileMaker Pro or you can get a free trial to get started.

The API for PHP talks to FileMaker Server only, not FileMaker Pro. However, the layout you need for the fields for your PHP script is made using FileMaker Pro, so you’ll need it for that at least.